# jpa / hibernate how to map element collection by foreign key with annotations

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Given these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `soc` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `soc_attitude` (
   `soc_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `target_soc_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `attitude` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`soc_id`,`target_soc_id`));
```

In the **Soc** class, I want to get all rows matching **this.soc_id** from the **soc_attitude** table using a field like this:

```
private Map<Integer,Integer> attitudes;
```

Where the key of the map is **target_soc_id** and the value is **attitude**.

I got as far as this:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "soc")
 public class Soc {
    @Id
    @Column( name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="soc_attitude",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="soc_id"))
    @Column(name="attitude")
    private Map<Integer,Integer> attitudes;
```

But I think this will make **soc_id** the key and **attitude** the value.

What annotations do I use? (using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @MapKeyColumn

Try this:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="soc_attitude",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="soc_id"))
@Column(name="attitude")
@MapKeyColumn(name="target_soc_id")
private Map<Integer,Integer> attitudes;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. I saw this in the Hibernate collection mapping documentation, but it wasn't clear that it could be applied also to @ElementCollection.

Comment: what would it have to look like if `attitude` is a JPA entity? like `Map<Integer, Attitude> attitudes`. Getting SQL errors with it. Cheers

Comment: @Blauhirn ok fixed it myself: in that case, one needs to use `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable` instead of elem.collection and coll.table.